# How can I map another key to act as Fn key on a Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard, fn-key

I have a non standard keyboard attached to my Mac, and it does not have a Fn key. I wish it did. Luckily it has another key "help" that I never use.

How do I get my "help" key to be treated as the Fn key on my Mac?

Comment: Does this keyboard have a windows button?

Comment: @Campo Windows  button is commonly assigned the "Command" key of OS X.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a Windows button - but it has a "Help" button which I never use (I ome to superuser for Help you see :-)